# Unable to load images using Webpack file-loader

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-file-loader

According to the [file-loader usage documentation](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader#usage) I should be able to load images like:

```
test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
use: [
  {
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {}  
  }
]
```

And later via:

```
import img from './file.png';
```

Here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {}
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.glsl$/,
                loader: 'webpack-glsl-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                enforce: 'pre',
                loader: 'tslint-loader',
                options: { failOnHint: true }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
    },
    entry: {
        app: './src/index.ts'
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist'
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Output Manager'
        })
    ],
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/'
    }
};
```

This is how I am creating my `dev-server`:

```
const app = express();

const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
    publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
}));

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Listening on port 3000!\n');
});
```

Further my `src` structure is something like this:

```
src
|-images
| |- image.gif
|
|-app.ts
```

I am tryinbg to load the image in the `app.ts` as follows:

```
import img from './images/image.gif';

// ...

private loadImage(): void {
    const image = new Image();
    image.src = img;
    image.onload = () => {

    };
}
```

Unfortunately I get:

> GET http://localhost:8080/undefined 404 (Not Found)

In Chrome's dev-tools navigator I can see the image file under `webpack://./src/images/image.gif`. The contents look like this:

```
module.exports = __webpack_public_path__ + "9b626fa0956bfa785b543ef53e895d5e.gif";


//////////////////
// WEBPACK FOOTER
// ./src/images/image.gif
// module id = 109
// module chunks = 0
```

Also if I hover the `img` variable while debugging I can see the name string `"/9b626fa0956bfa785b543ef53e895d5e.gif"`. Logging the variable returns `undefined` though and the `image.onload` is never triggered.

If I call `http://localhost:8080/9b626fa0956bfa785b543ef53e895d5e.gif` in the browser I can see the image.

Any idea why I am unable to load the image although I can see it in the browser and the path string seems to be there?

**Edit #1:**

As I am using TypeScript I had to declare a module in order to import `.gif` files:

```
declare module "*.gif" {
  const content: any;
  export default content;
}
```

Then I found this [Github issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/331) where the fix for the issue was to import the file like `import * as styles from "styles.scss"`. So I tried to import like:

```
import * as img from './images/img.gif';
```

Unfortunately this results in:

> error TS2322: Type 'typeof "*.gif"' is not assignable to type
>   'string'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two issues here. First you should try to load your image file like `import * as img from './images/img.gif';`. You also have to use the image somewhere in order to actually load it. Importing alone does not trigger loading the file. But a simple `console.log(img);` should trigger it.

The second issue is the reason why you get this exception:

> error TS2322: Type 'typeof "*.gif"' is not assignable to type
>   'string'.

You should try and wrap the actual usage of the imported file like:

```
if (typeof img === 'string') {
    console.log(img);
}
```

This way the exception will not be triggered.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Wrapping the call of img into the if clause actually did solve the issue, ty!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet of my webpack configuration. This works well for loading images.

```
{
    test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g)$/i,
    exclude: [/node_modules/],
    loaders: [
        'file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
        'image-webpack-loader'
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you change path like this. Notice the 2 dots.

import * as img from '../images/img.gif';